# How to calculate the derivative of an Integral?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I know that

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\,\int_{a}^{x}f(t)\,dt=f(x)
$$

but what does

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\bigg|_{x=c}\,\int_{a}^{g(x)}f(x,t)\,dt
$$

give?

Thanks.

Comment: look at here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${ { \frac { { d } }{ { d }x }  }\left( \int _{ a }^{ g(x) } f(x,t)\, { d }t \right) =\, f{ ( }x,g\left( x \right) { ) }\cdot g'(x)\,  }+\int _{ a }^{ g(x) }{ \frac { \partial f }{ \partial x }  } \, { dt }$$
now plug $x=c$

Answer (score 1):

Go for the Libniz Rule for deriving under the sign of the integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Then as using Leibniz's rule you get a function of x, you just should substitute the x for a c